# Create a count loop within XML and output

Tags: xml, powershell, count

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
</object> -<object type="host"> 
<property value="4" name="id"/> 
<property value="briu065a" name="name"/> 
<property value="2" name="port_count"/> 
<property value="generic" name="type"/> 
<property value="11111111111111111111111111111111111" name="mask"/>       
<property value="4" name="iogrp_count"/> 
<property value="offline" name="status"/> 
<property value="10000000C94EA2C9" name="WWPN"/> 
<property value="0" name="node_logged_in_count"/> 
<property value="offline" name="state"/> 
<property value="10000000C94EC64E" name="WWPN"/> 
<property value="0" name="node_logged_in_count"/> 
<property value="offline" name="state"/> 
<property value="10000000C94ECFEF" name="WWPN"/> 
<property value="0" name="node_logged_in_count"/> 
<property value="offline" name="state"/> 
</object>
<object type="hostio_grp"> 
<property value="4" name="host_id"/> 
<property value="0" name="id"/> 
<property value="iogrp_ab" name="name"/> </object>
```

Hi, I'm wondering if you can offer me some guidence here. I'm reading the above XML data and reporting out to a csv file. I am looking to take each value in the XML file and store it as an individual variable.

For single entries under type="host" such as "name" and "mask" I can extract the value into an individual variable easily, but when there are multiple values with the same name such as "WWPN" I'm finding it difficult to capture these multiple entries into seperate variables.

From the below code, I was hoping something like this would work:

```
if ($type -eq "host" -and $name -eq "WWPN" ) {$wwpn[$cnt] = $value.$cnt++
add-content $hostinfo "$hname,$wwpn(1),$wwpn(2),$wwpn(3)"}
```

I would like the csv ouput to basically look like this:

hname,    wwpn1,           wwpn2,           wwpn3
briu065a    ,10000000C94EA2C9,10000000C94EC64E,10000000C94ECFEF

I'm fairly new to Powershell, so any guidance would be much appreciated. Here is my code below:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $XMLPath\*.xml
foreach ($file in $files)
   {
   $xmlOutput=select-xml -path $file -XPath *
   foreach ($object in $xmlOutput.node.object)
       {
       $type=$object.type 
       foreach ($property in $object.property)
          {
          $name=$property.name
          $value=$property.value 
          if ($type -eq "host" -and $name -eq "name" ) {$hname = $value}
          if ($type -eq "host" -and $name -eq "WWPN" ) {$wwpn  = $value 
          add-content $hostinfo "$hname,$wwpn"}
          }     
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this seems to work:

```
$xmlOutput = New-Object XML
$files = Get-ChildItem $XMLPath\*.xml

foreach ($file in $files) {

   $xmlOutput.Load($file.FullName)
   foreach ($object in $xmlOutput.object) {

       $type = $object.type
       $line = $null
       foreach ($property in $object.property) {

          If ($type -eq "host") {$line += $property.value + ","}
       }
       If ($line -ne $null) {$line = $line.TrimEnd(",")}
       Add-Content $hostinfo "$line"
   }     
}
```

I would suggest further reading, but couldn't find the article that helped me most. This is one: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/08/19/mastering-everyday-xml-tasks-in-powershell/

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. Let me explain further. I am looking to add certain XML node information into variables and only output them variables to a CSV file, in prep to upload to a SQL database. I'll update my note above